# Write a program in C that inputs one six-digit number and prints the number again with spaces

Tags: c, scanf, division, modulo

Fun puzzle: Write a program in C that inputs one six-digit number from the keyboard and prints the number again and on a new line prints the digits separated from one another by four spaces each. Use combinations of integer division and the remainder operation (% operator)

My original idea was to do a work around with this but it's not the correct way of doing it.

```
    #include <stdio.h>

    int main(void)
    {
    char a,b,c,d,e,f;
    printf("Please enter a 6 digit number:");
    scanf("%c%c%c%c%c%c",&a,&b,&c,&d,&e,&f);

    printf("The number you inputted is:\n");
    printf("%c%c%c%c%c%c\n",a,b,c,d,e,f);
    printf("The number you entered, with spaces, is:\n");
    printf("%c    %c    %c    %c    %c    %c\n",a,b,c,d,e,f);

    return 0; 
    }
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because - this is simple homework.

Comment: The "**Related**" column on the right side of the page is often a useful starting point for related questions. The 'Displaying the digits of an integer..." link seems promising.

Comment: @elcuco "*this is simply homework*" is *not* a valid reason to vote for closure. Please review [**What types of questions should I avoid asking?**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) before labeling questions as off-topic.

Comment: To fulfill the  "Use combinations of integer division and the remainder operation" requirement, use `return 0%2/1;`

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the logic entirely to conform to the requirement. I'll not provide you any code, but will be happy to assist you with the logic.

1. Read the integer value as `int` (or `long int`, because the safe bet to store 6-digit number need to have at least 32-bit width variable)
2. Perform modulo-10 operation to get the Least significant digit. print or store.
3. Divide by 10.
4. Go back to step 2 until you have looped 5 more times i.e, the division yields 0.

Comment: Use a `long` though, an `int` might be too small.

Comment: Sourav, reading characters and treating everything as characters would be fine. He might only need to check for `isdigit`.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie did you miss "integer division and the remainder operation" in the question? :)

Comment: ..ah, I see.. he is not doing his homework properly.

Comment: @Bathsheba 16 bit `int`s? Yes, that can be the case, let me update...

Comment: This isn't homework. It's a extra-curricular puzzle between myself and a few friends. The way I did it is the only way I really know how to do it, hence why I'm seeking inspiration here :)